# ssh-keygen -l -f file is failing with dsa key content

Tags: ssh-keygen

My ssh-keygen -l -f  fails for dsa keys with error "not a public key file" but works fine for rsa key. The content is correct . What might be the reason. Anyway to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you showed the entire command line that you typed.

The reason is probably given in the error message. The filename you specified after the `-f` argument does not contain a public key (it contains a private key). Often public keys end with a `.pub` filetype.

Comment: it is .ssh file so basically the file format is ok